Is this true: We can use "will" to talk about any situation in the future; sometimes we don't use it just because we want to stress something else
I've found an interesting statement in a post about whether to use future simple or future continuous:

You use them according to what you want to stress. If you simply want to convey an information in a neutral way, simple future is fine. If you want to stress that it is a continual process, or if you are thinking of a particular moment in the future, when that action will be going on, then you can use the future continuous.

Does this mean that we can use "will" (future simple) to talk about any situation in the future; sometimes, we don't use it just because we want to stress something else?
For example, if a native speaker is planning on watching a movie with their mom at 10 p.m. tonight, they can still use the future simple as it generally conveys, "in a neutral way", that the action will happen in the future.


I will watch a movie with my mom at 10 p.m. tonight. (Even though they planned this before speaking, this sentence is not grammatically incorrect because they just want to talk about it "in a neutral way".)


However, that native speaker (almost?) never says it that way because whenever they plan on watching a movie with their mom in the future, they want to stress that it's a plan, so they use, say, the present continuous, so that the listener knows that it's a plan.
First question: Is my theory correct?
That sounds pretty convincing to me, but then I thought, "I never heard anybody using the future simple for a plan like that. Why don't English native speakers want to talk about things in a neutral way more?"
In my language, there is no tense, and there is a general word, i.e. sẽ, to use whenever we want to talk about the future. We just add sẽ before the verbs to imply that it'll happen in the future. That's it. It's so simple. But if my logic in the title is correct, why do native speakers always try to be specific instead of wanting to talk about things in a neutral way?

I’m voting to close this question because asking "why" native speakers don't want to speak in a neutral way more often i.e. using pure future, is unanswerable.

I personally would use shall or am going to rather than will.

I’ve just edited my question to stress the actually more important question: Is my theory true?

Could you tell me how I can make my question better? I've tried but haven't got why the question in the title, which is further clarified in the body, is unanswerable.

You could use the auxiliary "will" every time you want to express a future event. You could say (1) They will study at the weekend. But we can equally say (2) They study at the weekend (3) They are studying at the weekend (4) They're going to study at the weekend (5) They'll be studying at the weekend (6) They'd (would) like to study at the weekend (7) They might study at the weekend (8) They shall study (now obsolete) (9) They should study.

And you want to know why all these different future forms exist instead of one? Do you think there is one reason or maybe dozens?

Then you have misunderstood the questions. I know that each tense delivers a specific meaning and they are all necessary to help the listener understand exactly what you are saying. I never questioned why other tenses exist. Whatever the answers are to my two questions, of course I'll still try to use tenses appropriately. However, knowing the answers helps me explain English grammar to my students better. Sometimes, there are questions that seem absurd to native speakers, but if you were Vietnamese, you'd immediately get why I asked these.

You probably think my questions are ridiculous. Meanwhile, I also don't understand 100% why you think so, even though I'm trying to guess the reason. I think it is because we speak two completely different languages in terms of grammar--there are no tenses in Vietnamese. But I'd appreciate it if you could kindly clear it up for me. I'm a teacher, not a young student, and please trust me that I didn't ask these questions for stupid reasons.

My student asked me if he could say, "Next year will mark my grandparents' fiftieth anniversary." It sounds perfectly okay to me, but this doesn't fall into any pure future uses that I know, such as a spontaneous decision, a prediction, or a promise. Another one is: "Come on, the plane will take off soon."...

This is why when I saw the comment that I quoted in my OP, I really wanted to call my student and explain to him that: You can use pure future to talk about the future in a general, nonspecific way, like how we use "sẽ" in Vietnamese. So, your sentences are correct, but note that in many other cases, when there is a better tense to use, you must use that tense instead to be specific and help the listener understand what you intend to say better. But I want to confirm this first.

When you want to talk to a user directly you must use @+username, as in @Phoebe. There are two users who commented. But because I am writing beneath a question of yours you will always be notified. I came back to see if anyone else answered your question. Why would you teach or explain to a student something one person said in an answer? You probably have read dozens of English grammar books by now, has any mentioned "neutral future"? The "will form" is often called pure future. (Cont'd)

Native people  don't consciously tell themselves "I want to talk about a planned event, so I'll use the Present Continuous form.” It comes automatically.  Your questions are 1) Does this mean that we can use "will" (future simple) to talk about any situation in the future…? 2)  Why don't English native speakers want to talk about things in a neutral way more?" 3) … why do native speakers always try to be specific instead of wanting to talk about things in a neutral way? This is why in my opinion, the question(s) is unanswerable. You would need a book to explain why.

As for ""Next year will mark my grandparents' fiftieth anniversary." It is perfectly acceptable and grammatical because the will form is also used for stating facts. "The exam results will be sent at the end of the day" "In February I will turn 40" "Water will change into ice when it reaches 0°C" etc.

@Mari-LouA I see. Somehow the books I've read didn't mention the "stating facts" use at all. Many thanks!

Predictions//
We use will and shall to make predictions and to state facts about the future:

The Free Dictionary site has a thorough explanation of the many uses of "will" and "won't" https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Future-Simple-Tense.htm

Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

@KateBunting Your preference for "shall" marks you as a Brit, I think. Americans tend to prefer "will" to "shall".

@Phoebe Your comment is confusing. So, your sentences are correct, but note that in many other cases, when there is a better tense to use, you must use that tense instead to be specific and help the listener understand what you intend to say better.

The simple future is often used when you want to specify a particular time that an activity will start:

I will watch a movie at 10 tonight.

suggests that you will start watching at 10. In comparison, using future continuous

I will be watching a movie at 10 tonight.

implies that you'll start watching sometime before 10, and you'll still be watching at 10.
The latter is often used when the discussion involves activities that are expected to overlap. For instance, if your friend says they're going to call you at 10, you may say what activity you'll be in the middle of at that time:

Don't call me then, I'll be watching a movie with my mom. 9 or 11 would be better.


I. Use of future tense for future actions.

That sounds pretty convincing to me, but then I thought, "I never heard anybody using the future simple for a plan like that.
Why don't English native speakers want to talk about things in a neutral way more?"

I think OP has generalized the topic and come to the conclusion that the future tense is rarely used by the native speakers.
Consider these sentences, where future tense is the best choice:
1.I will reply to the email after lunch.
2.I will call my mom in the evening.
3.I will be working on the new project next month.
4.I will be sending the goods by courier.
5.I will drink coffee at Starbucks tonight.
(It is possible to rewrite some of the sentences using "going to" but it can't be directly written in the Present Continuous tense)
OP's sentence is the correct form to use when the plan was initially made.

I will watch a movie with my mom at 10 p.m. tonight.

The choices for talking about the future are.

will & will be Ving for unplanned future events.
going to + verb for planned future actions.
Last week, they decided they are going to get married in December..
Present continuous tense for planned future events.
We can use the present continuous if it is not an intention and has become an arrangement now.

The tenses used for the future are described below (Ref. britishcouncil.org, with my explanation in bold and italics.
I.Will.

We use will to talk about spontaneous plans decided at the moment of speaking.

Suppose your friend called you on Monday and informed you that they have planned a pot luck party on the weekend.
You reply, "I will bring fruit salad." (You decided at the time of speaking.)
II.going to.

We use going to to talk about plans decided before the moment of speaking.

Now suppose a friend called you on Wednesday and asked, "What are you bringing for the party?".
You reply, "I am going to bring fruit salad." (As you have planned this on Monday).
III.Present continuous tense...

We usually use the present continuous when the plan is an arrangement – already confirmed with at least one other person and we know the time and place.

Now when you are preparing the fruit salad on Saturday. You tell a friend, "I am bringing fruit salad for the party."
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/future-forms-will-be-going-present-continuous
